# move elements in a twig form depending on your needs - Symfony 3

Tags: css, symfony

I have a rendered form in my view which I need to shape regarding the mock-up.

and this is the mock up I shall follow (this is on a mobile device)

[image]

this is the actual layout I have in my view

[image]

and this is the code in my view so far

```
<section class="restaurant__nav col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-3 well">
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {% if app.user %}
                <input type="submit" value="{{ 'buy.field' |trans |upper }}">
            {% else %}
                {{ 'not_connected.text' |trans }}
            {% endif %}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</section>
```

So I'm really not good with sass (as i'm using it) and css either. But I tried to `margin` each element but I find it struggling a little.

Any good advice or method to actually do like my mockup without using too much pixels or avoiding that kind of things -> `margin-left: 20px`?

(just ignore the `RÉSERVER` I really try to put my form in the middle and element to equal sizing)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, if you didn't notice you are using Bootstrap.
It means that to align in left side and in the middle your two main block, you can use class like : "col-md-*". It's the grid concept of bootstrap, basic.
Here is a reference : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

Once block are correctly placed, you have to make the button and input together. Commonly called "input-group". You can implement this by many way, here is a reference : [getbootstrap.com](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/)

Then for your button, you have some good examples again on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp)

Once that's done, you may'd like to know that you can center element with :

```
display: block; // if element isn't natively block
margin: auto;
```

To know what html element is considered by css as **Block** or **Inline** elements, again another reference : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

To end this, you'd probably like to fix the width of the label and input as the same value.

I made you more than an example, my bad, but here it is :
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8dd66gr/)